# call method from fragment to fragment ( refresh adapter )

Tags: java, android, load, adapter

Hello I am trying to call this function `loadFiles()` which is located in `fragmentB` and I want to call it from `FragmentA`, so I can refresh my `GridView` for my images and videos.

I get this error from the same method

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

my method in `FragmentB`:

```
  public void loadFiles(){
        gridView = (GridView) this.v.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        File f = new File(home);
        if (f.exists()){
            String [] media = f.list();
            ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0; i<media.length;i++){
                if (media[i].endsWith(".jpg")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".png")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".JPEG")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".3gp")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".mp4")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".mov")){
                    files.add(media[i]);
                }

                if (i==media.length-1){
                    GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this.v.getContext(), files, gridView);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How I do call it in `FragmentA`:

```
FragmentB b = new FragmentB();
b.loadFiles();
```

I think the problem is because of this line but I have tried everything and there is no luck :(

```
GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this.v.getContext(), files, gridView);
```

Comment: Try to implement loadFiles() at Activity level instead any Fragment and use it on any Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do like this:

```
 public class Utils{
 public static ArrayList<String> loadFiles(){
         File f = new File(home);
        if (f.exists()){
            String [] media = f.list();
            ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0; i<media.length;i++){
                if (media[i].endsWith(".jpg")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".png")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".JPEG")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".3gp")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".mp4")||
                        media[i].endsWith(".mov")){
                    files.add(media[i]);
                }
            }
            return files;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in FragmentA and FragmentB etc. you can do

```
  gridView = (GridView) this.v.findViewById(R.id.grid);
     GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this.v.getContext(), Utils.loadFiles(), gridView);     
       gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I did it .. nothing changed .. the problem occur when I write this         gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
in the Fragment A it give me the error .. but I do need to so I can update my grideView of my adapter :/

Comment: I found the problem just call getActivity instead of this.v.getContext() .. I used your answer also so I will give you the right answer .

Comment: i didn't change that yes you have to use `getActivity()` instead of `this.v.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

See this link [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), you will find all required details; also you can download zip file containing sample app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a fragment method is because that fragment exists, so you can find and call it with:

```
Fragment2 myFragment = (MyFragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_NAME");
myFragment.method();
```

If it doesn't exist and you have to instantiate it from Fragment1, then maybe your strategy is not correct and you should put your code in your activity.